# C# How to detect if two strings are identical in a text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program and it is writing a save file. It currently does this by checking a listbox and simply writing down its contents in a textfile.

What I want is that if the textfile detects 2 identical strings in a text file, it will delete one of them.

```
path = @"C:\thing.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
    fs.Close();
}

if (checkedListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    using (TextWriter tw = File.AppendText(path)) 
    {
        foreach (string fileName in fullFileName) 
        {
            foreach (string item in checkedListBox1.Items)
                tw.WriteLine(fileName); //writes file path to textfile
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //nothing to do! There is nothing to save!
}
```

And lets say that in the textfile, contains this:

```
C:\Jack.exe
C:\COolstuff.exe
```

I do not want the textfile to have

```
C:\Jack.exe
C:\COolstuff.exe
C:\Jack.exe
```

Instead I want it to delete that third line: C:\Jack.exe since it matches the 1st line.

Comment: Throw them all to a list as you read don't add dupes to the list.  Write contents of list to your text file.

Comment: for one thing don't write them many times - once per checkbox checked :)

Comment: where does `fullFileName' come from?

Comment: @Trey I wish I could go into more context, but my application works by saving upon exit. if someone had those 2 saved and sure and it brought it up, but then exited with those still in the list, it would add them again. And I don't want them to add it again because in the listbox it will then present it multiple times.

Comment: @StenPetrov that is just stuff i'm writing to the text file. The listbox contains paths to programs. I am writing down those paths in the textfile.

Comment: Do you care about case sensitivity? In other words, do you consider `c:\jack.exe` to be the same as `c:\Jack.exe`?

Comment: why do you have the second `foreach`? You aren't doing anything with the `checkedListBox1.Items` that you're iterating over. This code will add each `fileName` to `fullFileName` multiple times if there are multiple items in the list box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code I believe you can use LINQ's Distinct() to accomplish this quickly.

```
foreach (string fileName in fullFileName.Distinct())
```

This will cause `foreach` to return only unique strings.  Remember you may need to add a reference to the LINQ namespace.  If you get an error on Distinct() put your cursor on it and use `ctrl+,` to have VS suggest that for you.

Comment: Sadly, does not work. There was no error in the code. It just copies the same content down twice still.

Comment: @RohanPas that's what I meant in my comment to your question - don't write it multiple times. You pick a file name and write it as many times as there are checkboxes checked

Answer (score 0):

What you could do if you want to delete the duplicates in a text file is read all lines in a array than change it to a List so you can use `Distinct()` and then rewrite to your text file with the new List like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

List<string> list = lines.ToList();

list = list.Distinct().ToList();

File.WriteAllLines(filePath, list.ToArray());
```

More information on [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, since you only want to save unique values, then it might be good to read your saved values first so you can compare them to the new ones.

The code flow would look something like:

1. Does the save file exist?

   - no  --> create empty fileName list
   - yes --> read save file contents into fileName list
2. For each item in the checked list box

   - if the fileName list does not contain it, add it to a newFiles list
3. Append the contents of the newFiles list to the file

In practice, this might look like:

```
string saveFilePath = @"c:\data\savedFiles.txt";
List<string> savedFileNames = new List<string>();
List<string> newFileNames = new List<string>();

// If our save file exists, read all contents into the 'saved file' list
if (File.Exists(saveFilePath))
{
    savedFileNames.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(saveFilePath));
}

// For each item in our check box, add it to our 'new 
// file' list if it doesn't exist in the 'saved file' list
foreach (var checkedItemin CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    if (!savedFileNames.Contains(checkedItem))
    {
        newFileNames.Add(checkedItem.ToString());
    }
}

// Append our new file names to the end of the saved file (this
// will also create the file for us if it doesn't already exist)
File.AppendAllLines(saveFilePath, newFileNames);
```